# Using randomR to generate a tuple of random values

Tags: haskell, random

I'm working through [this introduction to the State monad](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/State#Example:_Rolling_Dice) and, in one of the introductory examples, we come across the following code (it's called `clumsyRollDice` in the article)...

```
rollDice3 :: (Int, Int)
rollDice3 = (n,m)
  where
    (n,g) = randomR (1,6) (mkStdGen 0)
    (m,_) = randomR (1,6) g
```

...which doesn't compile (as you can see below).

What am I missing?  Did the implementation of one of the functions/classes from `System.Random` change since the example was published?

```
statemonad.hs:15:5:
    No instance for (Random t0)
      arising from the ambiguity check for ‘g’
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    When checking that ‘g’ has the inferred type ‘StdGen’
    Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
    In an equation for ‘rollDice3’:
        rollDice3
          = (n, m)
          where
              (n, g) = randomR (1, 6) (mkStdGen 0)
              (m, _) = randomR (1, 6) g

statemonad.hs:16:13:
    Could not deduce (RandomGen t0) arising from a use of ‘randomR’
    from the context (Random t, Num t)
      bound by the inferred type of m :: (Random t, Num t) => t
      at statemonad.hs:16:5-27
    The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance RandomGen StdGen -- Defined in ‘System.Random’
    In the expression: randomR (1, 6) g
    In a pattern binding: (m, _) = randomR (1, 6) g
    In an equation for ‘rollDice3’:
        rollDice3
          = (n, m)
          where
              (n, g) = randomR (1, 6) (mkStdGen 0)
              (m, _) = randomR (1, 6) g
Failed, modules loaded: none.
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
```

**Update:** 
The following fixes the code but I'm still curious re: what changed (i.e., in the compiler/etc) that results in an error when running the verbatim version of the code:

```
rollDice3 :: (Int, Int)
rollDice3 = (n,m)
  where
    (n,g) = randomR ((1::Int),6) (mkStdGen 0)
    (m,_) = randomR (1,6) g
```

Comment: The implementation of `randomR` depends on `randomIvalIntegral` since like 2010, so nothing changed "recently"

Comment: Haha, fair enough, I should be more careful when saying "recently"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this file, saved as `test.hs`.

```
module Main (main, clumsyRollDice) where
import System.Random
clumsyRollDice :: (Int, Int)
clumsyRollDice = (n, m)
        where
        (n, g) = randomR (1,6) (mkStdGen 0)
        (m, _) = randomR (1,6) g

main = putStrLn (show clumsyRollDice)
```

This file compiles under `ghc test.hs` but fails under `ghc test.hs -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` with an error very similar to what you're reporting. Do you have `NoMonomonomorphismRestriction` set in ghci?

A very similar case is discussed in this mailing list thread:

[Unexpected ambiguity in a seemingly valid Haskell 2010 program](https://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2012-November/023037.html)

The monomorphism restriction is discussed in detail on the wiki:

[Monomorphism restriction](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)

Comment: Yep, this is precisely the reason for the error.  I do indeed have the monomorphism restriction turned on. (Actually, I'm running ghc 7.8.3, which has it on by default.)   Thanks